# Converting .wav files to .aiff in c#

Tags: c#, audio, file-conversion

I'm trying to write a class that will convert .wav files to .aiff files as part of a project.

I've come across a couple of libraries Alvas.Audio (http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,overview.aspx) and NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com)

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with either of them as I'm really struggling to work out how to write a file in aiff format using either library.

I have the following code so far but I can't work out how to define the outfile as an aiff:

Alvas

```
string inFile = textBox1.Text; 
WaveReader mr = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(inFile));
IntPtr mrFormat = mr.ReadFormat();
IntPtr wwFormat = AudioCompressionManager.GetCompatibleFormat(mrFormat, AudioCompressionManager.PcmFormatTag);
string outFile = inFile + ".aif";
WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(outFile), AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(wwFormat));
AudioCompressionManager.Convert(mr, ww, false);
mr.Close();
ww.Close();
```

NAudio

```
string inFile = textBox1.Text;
string outFile = inFile + ".aif";

using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inFile))
{
   using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outFile, reader.WaveFormat))
   {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int bytesRead = 0;
       do
       {
           bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       } while (bytesRead > 0);
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatfully accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

The `WavWriter` from Alvas and the `WaveFileWriter` from NAudio are both designed to create WAV files, not AIFF files. NAudio does not incude an AiffFileWriter, and I don't know about Alvas, but AIFF files are not commonly used on Windows platforms. They use big-endian byte ordering (WAV uses little-endian) and the AIFF file format has different "chunk" definitions to the WAV file.

The basic answer is you'd probably have to create your own AIFF writing code. You can read the [AIFF specification here](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/AIFF/Docs/AIFF-1.3.pdf). You basically need to create a FORM chunk, which contains a COMM (common) chunk follwed by a SSND (sound data) chunk. The specification explains what to put in these chunks (it is fairly straightforward). The main thing you'll need to remember on Windows is to swap the byte ordering around.

Comment: Alvas 7.1 also does not support AIFF.

Comment: Yeah that's conclusion I came to today. It sounds simple in theory although I'm finding in practice it's not so simple. Aumplib is another library albeit a just a wrapper that seems to clover exactly what I need (it has a AiffWriter) although it doesn't appear to PInvoke the DLL very well anymore. I'm surprised there are no libraries I can pay for that satisfy this need!

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of Alvas.Audio see code below from: [How to convert .wav to .aiff?](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip133)

```
static void Wav2Aiff(string inFile)
{
    WaveReader wr = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(inFile));
    IntPtr inFormat = wr.ReadFormat();
    IntPtr outFormat = AudioCompressionManager.GetCompatibleFormat(inFormat, 
        AudioCompressionManager.PcmFormatTag);
    string outFile = inFile + ".aif";
    AiffWriter aw = new AiffWriter(File.Create(outFile), outFormat);
    byte[] outData = AudioCompressionManager.Convert(inFormat, outFormat, wr.ReadData(), false);
    aw.WriteData(outData);
    wr.Close();
    aw.Close();
}
```